# vb how to find a string in a string and return the string into a variable

Tags: vb.net

im trying to read a string from a dictionary and compare to my password and take the founded work and put it into a variable.

I have already tried using the instr but it only returns the position and not the value.

```
Dim mypos As Integer
     For i = 0 To UBound(dictionary_english, 1)
       mypos = 1
       mypos = InStr(password, dictionary_english(i))   
       If mypos > 0 Then Exit For Else
     Next
```

I am trying to achieve the following. 
mainstr= "sefsfdogsdfr"
searchstr= "dog"
search mainstr for dog and return just dog into a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, because if the searchstr exists in mainstr you can just return the searchstr. You do not need to take it out of your mainstr? Also if you use VB.NET you should (could) use IndexOf instead of InStr to be more in line with .NET.

Comment: oh thanks completely forgot of indexof thanks a lot

Comment: .....And next time you post a question including `UBound` and `InStr` you should Tag your question as VB6 and not VB.NET.

Comment: @video.baba : Just because he's using `UBound` and `InStr` that doesn't mean he's using VB6. They are originally from VB6, yes, but [both](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.ubound?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods are [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.instr?view=netframework-4.7.2) in VB.NET as well (annoying as it is, after all these years). What you don't normally do in VB6 however is to call the methods using parantheses. So if you see a piece of code without, you know it's VB6.

Comment: But you already have "dog" in a variable (searchstr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses a few of the replacements for old VB methods that .net offers. It will be easier to look at C# code if you are on the same wavelength with .net methods and you will be looking at C# code as most examples are being written in c#.

```
Private dictionary_english() As String = {"sam", "PeterdogRabbit", "George"}
Private Function ExistsInDictionary(StringToSearch As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    For index = 0 To dictionary_english.GetUpperBound(0)
        If dictionary_english(index).Contains(StringToSearch) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim searchTerm = "dog"
    Dim IsInDictionary = ExistsInDictionary(searchTerm)
    MessageBox.Show(IsInDictionary.ToString)
End Sub
```